# UICollectonView not scrolling after being added programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I added messageCollectionView and inputContainerView with textField and button inside  as a subViews to my viewController.

In viewDidLoad if I do this sequence of adding subViews:

```
view.addSubview(messageCollectionView)
view.addSubview(inputContainerView)
```

than adding constraints for subviews...

Everything works fine except one thing - I can't scroll messageCollectionView cells.

But when I do this sequence of adding subViews:

```
view.addSubview(inputContainerView)
view.addSubview(messageCollectionView)
```

messageCollectionView fully covers inputContainerView, so I can't see it.

How can I solve it and make messageCollectionView scroll?

My viewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(messageCollectionView)
view.addSubview(messageView)
messageView.layoutSubviews()

view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: messageCollectionView)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0]|", views: messageCollectionView)
```

My inputContainerView is inside messageView

```
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: inputContainerView)
addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0(52)]", views: inputContainerView)
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you share more code and your constraint ?

Comment: mat, I just added more code. I'm using MVC

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused. You have `inputContainerView` and `messageView` can you share also those constraints?

Comment: messageView its just a swift file where I create my inputContainerView, textField and button and add constraints for them. I just added constraints for inputContainerView in my question(see the bottom of my question).

Comment: Than in my messageViewController I create an instance of my messageView and add this messageView as a subView

Comment: you add messageView to the view but you haven't set ant constraint and messageCollectionView cover the view horizontally and vertically. I would add messageView first with the height and then set messageCollectionView top or bottom anchor to the messageView, top or bottom anchor.

Comment: messageCollectionView have out of view cell item for  scrolling ?

Comment: mat, bottomAnchor works for me! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
view.addSubview(messageView)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: messageView)
messageView.layoutSubviews()
view.addSubview(messageCollectionView)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:|[v0]|", views: messageCollectionView)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:|[v0(80)][v1]|", views: messageView , messageCollectionView) // not sure what height you want for messageView
```

[image]